# Sanity Check - I have a select tag inside a form and I can't tab to it. I've explicitly set the tab index, not help

Tags: html, select

This is actually embarrassing, but I can't seem to tab to the select box and I've tried all I know to do.

```
<form action="trial.php" method="post">

           <div class="formLeftCol">

             First Name:<br/>
   Last Name:<br/>
   Address:<br/>

   City:<br/>
   Select State <br/>
   Zip Code:<br/>
   Phone:<br/><br/>
   <p class="emailLabel">
   Email:</p><br/>


                </div>

                <div class="formRightCol"> 
                  <input class="formInput" type="text" name="first" />
                  <input class="formInput" type="text" name="last" />
                  <input class="formInput" type="text" name="address" />
                  <input class="formInput" type="text" name="city" />

                <select tabindex=1 class="formInput" name="state">
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>

                    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>

                    <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>

                    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                    <option value="ME">Maine</option>

                    <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>

                    <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>

                    <option value="NY">New York</option>
                    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                    <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>

                    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                    <option value="TX">Texas</option>

                    <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>

                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select>

                  <input class="formInput" type="text" name="zip" />
                  <input class="formInput" type="text" name="phone" />

                  <input class="formInputEmail" type="text" name="email" />
                  </div>


              <input class="formButton" type="image" src="images/trial/submitbutton.png" alt="Submit button">

              </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either just remove the `tabindex` attribute from the select element (since other input elements doesn't have it), *or* set it on all other input elements as well, with the desired tabbing order as `tabindex` value.

Comment: [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd6YY/). Your actual problem lies somewhere else than in the information posted as far.

Comment: I just threw only this code into a test.html page and I still can't tab onto the state select.

Comment: Did you click the link and test it there?

Comment: And i removed all the css. no dice.

Comment: I can click the select box, that isn't an issue.

Comment: I can't use the tab key to navigate to it. That is the issue.

Comment: Yes clicked the link, that's a cool site. Can't tab to it there either.

Comment: It works fine here regardless of the browser. I've tried FF3, IE8, O10, S5 and C7 on Win7.

Comment: How about that it is firefox on mac specific. I just tested in windows and safari actually worked.

Comment: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Pressing+Tab+key+does+not+select+menus+or+buttons

Comment: Someone seriously needs to create a browser standard regulatory agency. I felt like a noob for an hour today.

Comment: check link it is mac Firefox specific. http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Pressing+Tab+key+does+not+select+menus+or+buttons